# XLSform for ODK - How do I change choices according to repetition?

Tags: forms, odk, xlm

Creating a form in XLSform for use with ODK I've run into a hitch with repetitions.

The user is asked on the first repetition of a question group to select a "subplot". Data is entered and then the questions repeat. However, on the second repetition the user is still able to select all "subplots". As an example:

User selects "subplot 1" and enters data. On the repeat "subplot 1" is still an option. The user can select it and fill in the data again. This overwrites previous data.

I would like to remove selected options for the nth repetition depending on what the user has already selected.

subplot is chosen from a list. I've tried to implement the idea in the "Patterns Everywhere" section of this site:

http://blog.cartong.org/2015/08/11/advanced-xls-forms-coding-1/

However XLSform offline by Nafundi throws errors in the 'relevant' column.

I'm not sure how to post code here for XLSform.